# Convert code snippets into a string representation for populating a code editor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string

I'm trying to write a code-editor using [react-live](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-live).

The following works, where I hardcode the sample code into a string:

```
const code="<div>hello</div";
...
<LiveProvider code={code}>
  <LiveEditor />
  <LiveError />
  <LivePreview />
</LiveProvider>
```

But, for more advanced usages (when there is more than a trivial amount of example code), it is not efficient to write code inside a string.
So, my underlying question is **how can we effectively write example code which populates a code-editor?**

Ideally, we could write the sample code in a separate module, as actual code, and then somehow read it in when setting up the code-editor component.
However, this doesn't work:

```
import sampleCode from "./sampleCode.jsx";
const code = sampleCode.toString(); // '[object Object]'
```

Additionally, defining the sample code right there within the file doesn't work:

```
const code = <div>hi</div>;
code.toString(); // '[object Object]'
```

How can I convert actual code snippets into a string representation?

Answer (score 1):

What if you create a sample string and export it from a js file then import it and pass it in the `code` prop. I don't see an issue here. You can also lazily import samples.

Here's a simple use case:

// codeSamples.js

```
export const sample = `
const Sample = (props) => {
    return (
      <h1>Sample!</h1>
    );
}
`.trim();
```

// Component.js

```
import { sample } from "./codeSample";

...
<LiveProvider code={sample}>
  <LiveEditor />
  <LiveError />
  <LivePreview />
</LiveProvider>
```